# Flask autoreload not reloading or picking up changes

Tags: python, flask

I have an app.py flask application, that I want to enable auto-reloading for. This is the entry point:

```
APP = Flask(__name__)
APP.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
# a lot of configurations ommited
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP.run(debug=True, port=5005)
```

When I run the app, I get this in the terminal:

```
/Users/George/myproject/venv/bin/python /Users/George/myproject/app.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5005/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 338-825-330
```

and when I modify one of my controllers it picks up that a change has occurred:

```
 * Detected change in '/Users/George/myproject/web_endpoints/user.py', reloading
```

but the change doesn't occur, and if I do another change, it never gets picked up (not reported in the terminal).

Comment: same issue here, did someone find a solution?

Comment: I've found you're better off tagging the file-mod timestamp on start-up and at the end of any iteration loop, and then exiting when the the timestamp has changed. Run an external loop to start it back up from scratch. Just a note "me too" - I just saw this issue again. Using apschedule, the app will dupe-schedule on reload. Added "atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())" but didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Flask is not recommended to use app.run() with automatic reloading as this is badly supported

Here's the comments in source code of Flask

```
def run(self, host=None, port=None, debug=None, load_dotenv=True, **options):

    """Runs the application on a local development server.
    ...        

    If you want to run the application in debug mode, but disable the
    code execution on the interactive debugger, you can pass
    ``use_evalex=False`` as parameter.  This will keep the debugger's
    traceback screen active, but disable code execution.


    It is not recommended to use this function for development with
    automatic reloading as this is badly supported.  Instead you should
    be using the :command:`flask` command line script's ``run`` support.

    ...  
    """
    pass
```

But you can force to use reloader like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=config.HOST, port=config.PORT, debug=True)
```

Take care, the `app.run()` must be wrapped with `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer.

Comment: it does, you can add `use_reloader=True` and it will do the trick :)

Comment: still stucks in reloading and doesn't work

Comment: @BenyaminJafari-aGn  The `app.run()` must be wrapped with `if __name__ == '__main__'`.